# How to horizontally center things in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a mock website of an online warehouse and I'm trying to position a bar 350px from the top and centered in the middle. I want the max width of the site to be 1920w, 1080h. I've tried several ways to do this and each of the ways I've tried haven't gotten what I'm looking for.

```css
margin: num auto;
```

Like I saw on another post resulted in the button on the left side.

```css
text-align: center;
```

I saw somewhere doesn't work

```css
margin-left: 50%;
```

It doesn't look evenly centered like a normal site should

I want the bar to sit in the middle to where the halfway point of the bar is in the middle.

```
|                  |mid|                 |
```

Comment: In order for your posts to not get down voted and also to have answers you need to be clear, keep it simple and show effort. Explain clearly what you are trying to do. Don't mention things that are irrelevant. Post the code and approaches you have tried.

Comment: There are many ways to center your content in CSS, all quite different. I'd suggest looking up tutorials online on centering things in CSS.